# No. of real solution of the equation $2^x = x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

No. of real solution of the equation $2^x = x^2$

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $f(x) = 2^x-x^2$

Now Differentiate both side w. r to $x\;,$ we get $f^{'}(x) = 2^x\ln(2)-2x$

Now Again Differentiate w.r to $x\;,$ we get $f^{''}(x) = 2^x\cdot \ln^2(2)-2.$

Now Again Differentiate w.r to $x\;,$ we get $f^{'''}(x) = 2^x\cdot \ln^3(2)>0\; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Now I did not understand How can I solve It.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Not clear why you're differentiating. Please see my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interesting GRE problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263386/interesting-gre-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to your function $ \ f(x) \ $ , since it is the difference of two continuous functions defined "everywhere".  If we take values of this function at some integer values of $ \ x \ $ , we have

$$ f(-1) \ < \ 0 \  , \ f(0) \ > \ 0 \ , \ f(1) \ > \ 0 \  , \ f(2) \ = \ 0 \  , \ f(3) \ < \ 0 \  , \ f(4) \ = \ 0 \  , \ f(5) \ > \ 0 \ \ ,   $$

which directly locates two real roots of our equation and points to a third lying in the interval $ \ ( -1 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ (that one would need to be found "numerically": it turns out to be about -0.767) .

It remains for us to show that there aren't any more.  For $ \ x \ < \ -1 \ $ , we are able to say that there won't be, since $ \ x^2 \ > \ 1 \ $ , but $ \ 0 \ < \ 2^x \ < \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ .  For $ \ x \ > \ 4 \ $ , we can look at the derivatives you calculated.  Depending on how fundamental an inequality we want to start from, we could take it that

$$ x \ - \ 1 \ > \ \ln x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (x-1) \ \ln 2 \ > \ \ln x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2^{x-1} \ > \ x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2^{x-1}  \cdot  \ln 2 \ > \ x   $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ f \ '(x) \ = \ 2^x  \cdot  \ln 2 \ - \ 2x \  > \ 0 \ \ .    $$

Also,

$$ 2^{x-1} \  \cdot \ (\ln 2)^2 \ > \ 1 \ \ , $$

so $ \ f \ ''(x) \ > \ 0  \ $ for $ \ x \ > \ 4 \ $ , meaning that $ \ f(x) \ $ is "concave upward".  Thus, $ \ f(x) \ $ continues increasing indefinitely, so there are no further real zeroes for the function, and no other roots of our equation.

**EDIT (6/6) --** I suppose we could be a bit more thorough about showing that there are no other real roots between the ones found above.  In $ \ ( -1 \ , \ 0) \ $ ,

$$ 0 \ <  -2x \ < \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ln 2 \ < \ 2^{-1} \cdot \ln 2 \ - \ 2x \ <  \ f \ '(x) \ < \ 2^0 \cdot \ln 2 \ - \ 2x \ < \  
 \ln 2 \ + \ 2  \ \ . $$

So $ \ f(x) \ $ is strictly increasing on this interval: there is only the one zero at $ \ \approx \ -0.767 \ $ .

Since $ \ 2^x \cdot (\ln 2)^2 \ $ is a positive number multiplying an exponential function, it is strictly increasing over all real numbers.  Thus, the second derivative $ \ f \ ''(x) \ = \ 2^x \cdot (\ln 2)^2 \ - \ 2 \ $ has only one real zero at $ \ x \ = \ \log_2 \left[ \frac{2}{(\ln 2)^2} \right] \ = \ 1 \ - \ 2 \ \frac{\ln  (\ln 2)}{\ln 2} \ \approx \ 2.0575 \ = \ \alpha \ $ ; this is the single point of inflection for $ \ f \ '(x) \ $ .

Thus, $ \ f(x) \ $ is positive and only "concave downward" on $ \ (0 \ , \ 2) \ $ ; there are then no other zeroes of $ \ f(x) \ $ in this interval.  The situation is a little more complicated in $ \ (2 \ , \ 4) \ $ , since the concavity of $ \ f(x) \ $ changes.  The function is negative and only "concave upward" on $ \ ( \alpha \ , \ 4) \ $ ; also, $ \ f \ '(2) \ < \ 0 \ $ . The function $ \ f(x) \ $  then should remain negative on $ \ (2 \ , \ 4) \ $ .

The difference of a transcendental function (the exponential function) and an algebraic function (the "power-law" function) make this a bit untidy to analyze.  Key features of $ \ f(x) \ $ don't fall at convenient values of $ \ x \ $ , and don't always appear in quite the intervals we might like...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: sketch the curves. http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiMl54IiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRjUwQTQxIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTUiLCI1IiwiLTEyLjQ5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5MSIsIjE5Ljk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5MyJdfV0-

That will tell you there are three real roots.

One root ($2$) is obvious and trivially found. So is the other positive root, which is $4$.

The third (negative real root) cannot be exactly determined but it can be approximated by numerical methods.

Comment: What about $x=4$? Isn't that a third root?

Comment: @DavidH It is, you're absolutely right. Will edit my post. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you need to have your graph extend further "vertically", since it doesn't currently show where the exponential function overtakes the quadratic one again.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Edited with a much better plot.

Comment: Thanks:  I only mentioned it because one of the roots you alluded to fell outside the "window"...